Can an Antminer KS3 be used to mine Bitcoin?
I bought an Antminer KS3, the Bitmain miner for the KHeavyHash algorithm hashrate and it arrived yesterday.
My question is, can I somehow modify the hardware of this KS3 to be able to mine bitcoin? I am interested in knowing if this is possible for a project that I have in mind. If someone can give me a little clarity on this matter, I would appreciate it.

Hey, we only accept content in English, so I translated your question and shortened it to the relevant information. Please use English in future posts.

No, Bitcoin uses SHA-256D for its hashing algorithm. The KS3 miner implements the kHeavyHash algorithm. Since Application Specific Integrated Circuits (ASICs) implement the mining algorithm directly in the silicon on the chip, it is not possible to modify the miner to use it for Bitcoin.
